# Strange behavior of Reflection::getProperties() with numeric keys

Tags: php, object, reflection, properties

```
$obj = (object)array('a', 'b', 'c');
$refl = new \ReflectionObject($obj);
$props = $refl->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | \ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);    

foreach($props as $prop)
  print $prop->name;
```

Prints some weird names, like `line`, `file` and `line` (instead of 1, 2, 3). Why? I realize the names are invalid because they are numbers, but then why do I get these random strings?

`get_object_vars($obj)` shows nothing, and `print_r((array)$obj)` actually prints the values correctly.

---

If Reflection can't display numeric properties, is there any way I can make it so it ignores them?

---

It also happens on many SPL interators (like `ArrayObject`s, `SplFixedArray`s, `SplHeap`s). Apparently this behavior is present in some PHP 5.3 versions only. PHP 5.4 shows nothing.

---

[Related PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49154) and my take on the solution ([`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) ignores invalid names):

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4') < 0){
  $props = array_filter($props, function($prop) use($obj){
    return !$prop->isPublic() || property_exists($obj, $prop->name);
  });
}
```

Comment: What about ArrayObjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a won't fix bug... or strange php behavior](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60379). So, you can't use object type casting if you are not sure about numeric keys in it. Use something like this

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    $obj->{$key} = $value;
```

---

You can use another dirty trick from strange php behavior. Get all properties without reflection.

```
$obj = (object) array('a', 'b', 'c');
$obj->{0}='asd';
while (list($field, $value) = each($obj))
    {
    var_dump($field, $value);
    }
```

Also i think this problem occurs only with stdClass objects.

Comment: It also occurs on any Iterator object, like ArrayObject, SplFixedArray etc :(

Comment: @OneTrickPony, can you print examples? And what about my trick?

Comment: It seems to work in the same way as my (array) cast solution. After more googling, I found that it's a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49154) in 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Casting an array to an object converts the array keys into property names, and the values to their values.

Your array has numeric keys. Your object has numeric properties. Which are sort of invalid.

You really want:

`$obj = (object) array('a'=> null, 'b' => null, 'c'=> null);`

Comment: Numeric fieldnames are legal. `$obj2 = new \stdClass(); $obj2->{'0'} = 'a';`

Comment: Not in PHP. This is a syntax error: `$obj->2 = "yey";` "syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'"

Comment: Your example does not use an integer value as the property name. It does use a string with a digit inside. This is the difference. Inside arrays, keys are always integers, never strings. So numeric values are highly problematic when used as property name, at least.

Comment: It is all in definitions. '0' is numeric in PHP definitions. `is_numeric('0');`. But there is another problem. Objects has string numeric fields names, but arrays numeric keys are always integer.

Comment: p.s. I can use integer too, but it will be converted to string. Look at bottom of [this article](http://nikic.github.com/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html).

Comment: My use case is a debug application that uses Reflection. If an object like in my example is given, I'd like to avoid showing random characters